# Do we need to regenerate subxt metadata after upgrading substrate node?

Tags: substrate-node-template, subxt

I have a Rust application, which is using Subxt library to connect with a running node and submitting the transaction. This application is running on 3 different instances.

I need to perform a runtime upgrade on my chain.

Do I need to regenerate the metadata of the target Substrate node after upgrade? If yes, should I replace metadata file with newly generated metadata on every instances?

Or

Its not needed?

Can someone please help me to provide the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, you should if you're using static mode.

Alternatively, utilize subxt's dynamic module; however, a reconnection is still required if your subxt application detects any runtime upgrades.

For instance, failing to do so could result in an outdated pallet list after a runtime upgrade. Consequently, your call index might become invalid.